# Swift - Accessing NSArray within Objective-C Class

Tags: objective-c, swift, serial-port, orsserialport

Good evening,

I'm currently trying to produce a list of all available serial ports in Swift using the ORSSerialPort Objective-C library. The current code is below, this just generates the NSArray that contains the available ports.

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class Serial {

    init() {
    }

    @IBOutlet var serialListPullDown : NSPopUpButton!

    func refreshSerialList(defaultprompt: String) {

        //Initialize ORSSerialPortManager
        let portManager : ORSSerialPortManager = ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager()
        var availablePorts : NSArray = portManager.availablePorts

        //Erase entries from popup field
        serialListPullDown?.removeAllItems()

    }
}
```

Currently, when I insert a breakpoint at:

```
var availablePorts : NSArray = portManager.availablePorts
```

When I work through the debug window (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkQDH.jpg) I see that I can find the path I'm looking for, in this case '/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem'. However this information seems to be hidden behind _path which should be a variable of the ORSSerialPortManager class but I cannot find it in the source files. Obviously the information is there, but how do I get to it in my Swift function?

Comment: can you try this? var availablePorts : NSArray = portManager.availablePorts as NSArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`availablePorts` is an `NSArray` of `ORSSerialPort` objects. It looks like you can directly access the [`path`](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort/blob/master/Source/ORSSerialPort.m#L59) property to get the data you're looking for.

```
var availablePorts : NSArray = portManager.availablePorts
for port in availablePorts as [ORSSerialPort] {
    println("Serial Port: \(port.path)");
}
```

Comment: I just went to try that but it gave me the error: Ambiguous use of 'path'

Comment: Ah, right, `availablePorts` should be cast to `[ORSSerialPort]` (native swift array) so that `port` ends up as the right type. I edited my answer.

Comment: This eliminates the Syntax errors but now the program crashes when it enters the for loop and shows this: http://imgur.com/Mx6vRCM

Comment: That's odd... are you using the latest Xcode beta? I wrote a quick little test app and that code worked fine for me in Xcode6-Beta6.

Comment: Well it was written in beta5 but I've since downloaded beta6 which is where I got this error.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your derived data for that project? Lots of people have been having weird issue upgrading from beta5 to beta6, and deleting derived data seems to fix most of them.

Comment: Oddly enough that seems to have fixed that error. How weird, thank you so much for all of your help and I look forward to pushing forward with this program!

Comment: Yep, from what I understand it has something to do with Xcode caching some data from the swift compiler and then not clearing that cache after upgrading. Anyway, glad I could help :)